# How to access slot attributes in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I've got a Vue component named MediaVisual. That componant contains a slot.

The problem is that I am trying to get the src attribute of the passed in slot element.
But `this.$slots.default` appears to be `undefined`. Eventhough before (in version 2) I used `this.$slots.default[0].attrs.src` to get the slot's SRC value.

This error happened since updating Vue to version 3... (it was version 2.5.7).

```
<template>
<figure :class="visualClass" :style="getPhotoBackgroundSrc()">

    <slot></slot>

    <div class="visual__text" v-show="this.show">
        <div class="visual__title">{{ title }}</div>
        <div class="visual__subtitle">{{ subtitle }}</div>
    </div>

</figure>
</template>
```

Here is the function inside `methods`:

```
 getPhotoBackgroundSrc() {
            let image_url = typeof this.$slots.default[0] !== 'undefined' ? this.$slots.default[0].attrs.src : '',
                css = '';

            if (this.position === 'center')
                css += 'background-position-y: center;';

            if (this.type === 'cover')
                css += ' background-image: url("' + image_url + '");';

            return css;
        },
```

Usage of slot:

```
<media-visual type="cover" title="" subtitle="">
     <img src="/photos/image.jpg" alt="" />
</media-visual>
```

So... what would be the correct way in Vue 3 to get the SRC attribute of a passed in slot element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vue 3 `this.$slots.default` is a function which should be called to return the nodes array, also use `props` instead of `attrs`:

```js
let image_url = typeof this.$slots.default !== 'undefined' ? this.$slots.default()[0].props.src : '',
```

[LIVE DEMO](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#eNp9UMtqwzAQ/BUhCrGhke5GLZT+hi6uvXYUrAfadVoI/veuZKfkVJ12VqOZ0dzlR0rqtoLspMEhu0QCgdb0boPzKWYSn9EnMeXoxUnpAgr9ZIPRO5+ZDAh8WnoCRkKYQqtTOcb5WWAe3qwkQFIpzFbqnVgFeTT6T0C+yt357PukrhgDZ7sXtj0u0MpO1E3ZcZqCrbwQJey0xmkoEa+oYp41TyqvgZwHBejPXzl+I2QWtrJIbDZsbPn42FMPHAt+agUjTP26ULX0kcVgbNojwBADxgXUEueGLg7VCy6RUB1vmrZ9uNSe/iltdLejM1Mk9oa4on3/3ND2C0fzlXo=)